# htaccess redirect catchall

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, catch-all

I need to redirect a directory, and all subdirectories and files in that directory, to the same location (root). So anyone who tries to visit `/old`, `/old/folder`, `/old/other-folder/xy/page.php`, or anywhere else within the 'old' folder, should be redirected to the root domain.

So far, I have this:

```
Redirect 301 ^/old/.*$ /
```

Is this the best way of doing it, or would it be better to use `(.*)` instead of `.*`? What is the difference between the two?

Or - should I use a RewriteRule instead of a Redirect like above? If so, why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `Redirect` directive doesn't use regular expressions. It connects 2 path nodes together, which isn't exactly what you want. You can try using the `RedirectMatch` directive instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old/ /
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^old/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If you just want to redirect every old page to homepage/root(I'm not sure exactly what you want) than you can replace last rewriterule with

```
RewriteRule ^old/.* / [R=301,NC,L]
```